# Join tables with values from JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, join

Im having problems querying data from json fields.

I have some json format columns saved as text in my postgres database (version 10)

Sometimes i need to be able to join two tables on json values.

I have no idea how i can do this..

Here is an simple example.

In my select i want to output the fruit and the color.

I have the color_cd number inside a json in the fruits table and i can find the color inside another json in the code_table.

My wished output should be like this

```
Fruit_ID   Name     Color
1000       Pear     Green
1001       Banana   Yellow
```

Fiddle link --> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3f989db0524e288183619bab63fc9add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column `records` on table `code_table` has problem in json data and i fixed problem and change to below format:

```json
{"color_cd":{"30":{"code":"30","color":"yellow"},"55":{"code":"55","color":"green"},"60":{"code":"60","color":"red"}}}
```

You can see query structure and result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f746d1733b904da8d24ac7d7edacf934)

```sql
select
 f.id,
 f.name,
 j_cd.value ->> 'color' as color
from 
  code_table ct 
  cross join jsonb_each(records::jsonb -> 'color_cd') j_cd
  inner join fruits f on f.type_cd :: jsonb ->> 'color_cd' = j_cd.key::text
where 
  ct.name = 'color_cd'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to have the fruits table as main? like from fruits f and do join on the code_table instead? In the query i have i need to have the fruits table as main table.

Comment: Yes, you can use second query of https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a9c0a40aea1a2a339be6dbd0254a567f

Comment: Sorry it's even more complicated.. 
I already have a lot of joins in the query and the fruits is not the "main" table.
It's looks something like this and now i have to build in your example to get the color
select t1.blabla,t3.blabla,t4.blabla,f.id,f.name, color
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.t2_id
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id = t2.t3_id
left join table4 t4 on t4.id = t3.t4_id
inner join fruits f on f.id = t4.fruits_id